# Joining and printing search results of a column with multiple values in a cell

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, join

I have 3 databases, details as follows.

I wish to print all columns in the books_db database plus each book's genre at the same time.

A book can fall into multiple genres, so I gave a unique ID to each genre. 
Genre_ID 1 - Thriller , Genre_ID 2 - Adventure etc.

```
--- books_db -----------
    ID          (int AI)
    Book_title  (varchar)
    Author      (varchar)


--- genre_link_db ------
    ID_Books    (int)
    Genre_ID    (int)


--- genre_db -----------
    Genre_ID    (int)
    Genre       (varchar)
```

So far, I've managed to code this SQL statement. It works, but it only works for the 1st search result as the group concat() will concatenate all genres together and not print a new line for the next search result.

For example below, if I try like '%' , which is supposed to show all results, it only shows 1 result with its genres correctly printed.

```
SELECT *, group_concat(T2.Genre separator ', ') AS GENRE_RESULT 
FROM (SELECT * FROM books_db WHERE Book_title like '%') AS T1 
JOIN (SELECT ID_Books, Genre from genre_link_db INNER JOIN genre_db ON genre_link_db.Genre_ID = genre_db.Genre_ID ) AS T2   
ON T1.ID = T2.ID_Books;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are missing is a GROUP BY-statement.

I would also rewrite the joining-part of your query. I don't think subselects is necessary here.

Something like this is what I would have done:

```
SELECT *, group_concat(T2.Genre separator ', ') AS GENRE_RESULT 
FROM books_db AS T1 
JOIN genre_link_db ON genre_link_db.ID_books = T1.ID
JOIN genre_db AS T2 ON genre_link_db.Genre_ID = T2.Genre_ID
WHERE books_db.Book_title like '%'
GROUP BY T1.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess I overthought the subselects :P .